# Beginner's guide - Crash log of expo eas built apk on the actual device

Tags: react-native, expo, crash, crash-reports

Good day
My expo react-native app works fine on Expo Go but crashes on the device after a successful EAS build.
Can anyone please either explain or direct to a good tutorial - How to get the crash reports from the device?

I am an absolute beginner so using acronyms or any explanation that assumes I have understanding of what is happening under the hood will not be useful.

I am using a mac and the app crashes on an Android.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but that was because of the library [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/)
and the splash screen. When it tries to move between screes from the splash screen to other screen.

I solve it by fowling this documentation [SplashScreen](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/)

PS: if you are using some fonts that need to be load first.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this wasn't my question. While I have currently a problem I need to resolve, I am interested in understanding the workflow of debugging a crash once I moved from Expo Go to a build on a device.